# Alternatives to find_by for ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working through Michael Hartel's rails tutorial, on 6.3 and need alternative code for the user_spec model.  The code that he has is:

```
let(:found_user) { User.find_by(email: @user.email) }
```

It looks like I can use where, but unsure of the correct syntax.  I tried several variations of the following:

```
let(:found_user) { User.where(:email => "@user.email")}
```

I'm sure this is a pretty easy answer, but cant quite get it.

Comment: fotanus,  thank so much for the edit and welcome.  I couldn't find the option to highlight the code, but, I'll double check next time.  I must still have a little "deer in the headlights". Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let(:found_user){User.where(email: @user.email).first}
```

or

```
let(:found_user){User.find_by_email(@user.email)}
```

That first one that uses `where` returns a collection of users that match the where clauses, which is why you would need that `.first`  (It doesn't execute the sql until you grab the records with something like `.all`, `.first`, or `.each`).

I would say it's not the best practice to execute database commands in a unit test though.  What are you testing specifically?  Is there a reason you need the user to be saved in the database and can't just do something like:

```
let(:user){User.new(email: 'some email')}
```

Comment: The right curly brace and parentheses are reversed in the first example. Otherwise this anwser is spot on.

Comment: haha and in the last example now too.:) No prob, I'd edit it myself for you if I had more than 2 characters to change.

Comment: I'd recommend not to use custom `find_by`s, I have a memory that those will be removed from rails.


Also @nzifnab is right pointing that isn't a good practice to create DB records in your tests, I'd recommend the FactoryGirl gem to improve this, if you want to https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl

Comment: Thanks all,  you guys are good and insanely quick.  I really didn't think I would get an answer.  I appreciate the detailed explinations.

Comment: I don't know what's going on with the `.find_by(email: 'stuff')` style of method, I've never used that kind of finder so I don't know if it's gone or not.  However I do know that `.find_by_email('stuff')` is not deprecated.  See a proper list in the README here: https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders  (I would not advise using this gem - there is no reason to want these old finders back).

Comment: Yes, the `.find_by_something('stuff')` and `.find_by(something: 'stuff')` methods are not deprecated. They are still valid as of the most recent version of Rails the time of this writing (4.0.0)

Comment: However, I'd personally still recommend using `.where`, since using `.find_by` and all those yet-to-be-deprecated methods do not return an active record relation, meaning you cannot chain other query methods together. For example, you **cannot** do something like `Foo.find_by_bar("baz").order(:bar)`.

Answer (score 1):

[`ActiveRecord::Base#find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) is effectively `where(options).first`, but that's a whole extra call that you needn't make.

Rails also provides [mildly deprecated](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/74abdb1eab2dffea6247af7653b994c1f1bfe2ef/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L162-L181) "magic" `find_by_<attribute>[and_<attribute>]` methods which used `method_missing` to parse out what was meant based on the name of the method. While the framework does provide these, I caution against using them as they are necessarily slower than "native" methods, and are more resistant to refactoring.

I would recommend sticking with `find_by` for the general case, and would try to avoid hitting the database in specs and tests.

The [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) gem provides a method to create a stubbed version of the class which quacks like a record returned from the database by answering `true` for `persisted?` and providing an `id`.

Alternatively, you can just build a new record without saving it: `User.new(attribute: value, ...)` and run your tests on that:

```
it "does some things" do
  user = User.new(attributes)

  # make user do some things

  expect(things).to have_happened
end
```

Comment: Actually `User.find_by_email(...)` - style finders are *not* deprecated.  See the deprecated_finders gem for a complete list of what is and what is not deprecated in the newest versions of rails: https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders

Comment: Hah, "mildly deprecated" in their documentation.  What in the heck does that mean?  In any case I'd probably prefer using either `.where` or `.find_by(email: 'stuff')` these days, even if the magic versions still exist.